# How to display UTF-8 in a HITextView (MLTE) control?

Tags: macos, unicode, macos-carbon, core-foundation

I have a UTF-8 string which I want to display in an HITextView (MLTE) control.  Theoretically, HITextView requires either "Text" or UTF-16, so I'm converting:

```
UniChar uniput[STRSIZE];
ByteCount converted,unilen;

err = ConvertFromTextToUnicode(C2UInfo, len, output,
                               kUnicodeUseFallbacksMask, 0, NULL, 0, NULL,
                               sizeof(UniChar)*STRSIZE,
                               &converted, &unilen, uniput);
err=TXNSetData(MessageObject, kTXNUnicodeTextData, uniput, unilen, kTXNEndOffset,
               kTXNEndOffset);
```

I have defined the converter `C2UInfo` as follows:

```
UnicodeMapping    uMapping;
uMapping.unicodeEncoding = CreateTextEncoding(kTextEncodingUnicodeV2_0,
                              kUnicodeCanonicalDecompVariant,
                              kUnicode16BitFormat);
uMapping.otherEncoding = GetTextEncodingBase(kUnicodeUTF8Format);
uMapping.mappingVersion = kUnicodeUseLatestMapping;
err = CreateTextToUnicodeInfo(&uMapping, &C2UInfo);
```

It works fine for plain old ASCII characters, but multi-byte UTF-8 is being mapped to the wrong characters.  For example, æ (LATIN SMALL LETTER AE) is being mapped to 疆 (CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-7586).

I've tried checking and unchecking "Output Text in Unicode" in Interface Builder, and I've tried varying some of the conversion constants, with no effect.

This is being built with Xcode 3.2.6 using the MacOSX10.5.sdk and tested under 10.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “Text” that `ConvertFromTextToUnicode` expects is probably the same “Text” that is one of your two options for MLTE. If you had the sort of “Text” that `ConvertFromTextToUnicode` converts from, you could just pass it to MLTE directly.

(For the record, “Text” is almost certainly either MacRoman or whatever is dictated by the user's locale-determined current script.)

Instead, you should use a Text Encoding Converter. [Create one](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Text_Encodin_sion_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/TECCreateConverter), [use it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Text_Encodin_sion_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/TECConvertText), [finish using it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Text_Encodin_sion_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/TECFlushText), and [dispose of it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Text_Encodin_sion_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/TECDisposeConverter) when you're done.

There are two other ways.

One is to [create a CFString from the UTF-8](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringCreateWithBytes), then [Get its characters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetCharacters). You would do this instead of using a TEC. It's functionally equivalent and possibly a little bit easier. On the other hand, you don't get to reuse the converter, for whatever that's worth.

The other, since you have an HITextView, would be to create a CFString from the UTF-8 and [just use that](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/HIViewReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/HIViewSetText). Like Cocoa objects, HIToolbox objects have an inheritance hierarchy; since an HITextView is a kind of HIView, `HIViewSetText` should just work. (And if not, try `HIViewSetValue`.)

The last method also gets you that much closer to your eventual move away from MLTE/HITextView, since it's essentially [what you'll do with an NSTextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSText/setString%3a). (HITextView and MLTE are deprecated.)

Comment: `HIViewSetText` would be ideal, if it respected updates to a mutable string.  The problem here is that text is being appended each time and will grow large.  In experimenting with `HIViewSetText`, it seems that if you give it a mutable string it ignores changes to that string.  The only way to append to an `HITextView` appears to be `TXNSetData`.  I will try the other methods next.

Comment: Creating a CFString and then getting its characters seems to do the job.  Interesting observation: `CFStringGetCharactersPtr` seems to return `NULL` (which it is allowed to do) when the original string is all ASCII, but a pointer to `UniChar[]` when the original string contained at least one extended unicode character.  So I infer that `CFString` does optimize its storage according to the characters it sees, which is nice.

Comment: @SethNoble: Re `HIViewSetText`, it probably makes its own copy (and I would expect this when you pass a buffer as well). You'll need to set the view's text each time you change the string. (This, too, would match how NSTextView behaves.)